# Console print formatting with "tibble.width = Inf"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I've been working with data.table for a little over a year but have recently been trying to get acquainted with the tidyverse for a number of reasons. One fairly basic challenge I'm encountering is viewing (`print()`) the output of any operations on columns that extend beyond my console window—without the need for additional functions (e.g. `glimpse()`, `select(), View()`). With `tibble.width = Inf`, I can see all columns in my tibble, but the formatting makes it pretty much unreadable. In contrast, data.table prints all columns by default, and does so by seemingly printing columnwise and wrapping the resultant output (which is far more readable). See the this screenshot using data from the `nycflights13`  library (as referenced by the [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/) book).
[image]

My questions:

- Is it possible to print a tibble to console with formatting similar to data.table, showing all columns in a readable format but without the need for  additional functions? Am I missing some options in dplyr or elsewhere?
- If not, how do dplyr users typically verify their outputs where columns extend beyond the console width? I'm so used to just quickly printing a data.table to verify any changes.

Comment: I usually verify my data using `View()` in RStudio